# I found this error (Sending 'const uint8_t (*)[kStreamChunkSize]' to parameter of type 'void *' discards qualifiers)?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have one method in NSData file.

```
 - (void)getBytes:(void *)buffer;
```

But when i used this method like..

```
  const uint8_t bytes [kStreamChunkSize];
  [chunk getBytes:&bytes];
```

Then its give this error

Sending 'const uint8_t (*)[kStreamChunkSize]' to parameter of type 'void *' discards qualifiers

How to solve this error. Please help me.

Comment: Side note: Better use `getBytes:length:` to avoid the possibility of a buffer overrun.

Comment: How could that work with a constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It discards the `const` qualifier and that's a problem. `getBytes:` gets the bytes by writing them into the array passed in. However, you can't write in an array of `const` bytes (doing so invokes undefined behavior), that's what `const` means. Change the declaration of your array to

```
uint8_t bytes[kStreamChunkSize];
```

Furthermore, don't pass a pointer to the array - if you simply use its name without the `&` operator, it will decay into a pointer to its first element anyway.

Comment: Thanks H2CO3. Can i cast this like  [chunk getBytes:(void *)&bytes]?

Comment: @AmitGujjar You can, but why would you ever do that? (Even better: why would you ever do it despite that I **just** explained why you should not use the addressof operator?)

Comment: @AmitGujjar: If you don't actually need a copy of the data, you can alternatively call `const uint8_t *bytes = [chunk bytes]`.